# React redux thunk how can I get one updated reducer value?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, try-catch, redux-thunk, redux-actions

I have a button with the handleRedeploy function on OnClick event and when click the button, it will fire handleRedeploy function then.

```
...onClick={() => {
   handleRedeploy(Project_ID)
}...
```

```
const handleRedeploy = (Project_ID) => {
   dispatch(redeploy(Project_ID))
}
```

Within the actions of redux, that redeploy action will dispatch two actions, one is cloneProjectRequest and another is cloneParticipantRequest. The cloneProjectRequest will create a new project and the cloneProjectRequest will use that new project Id as well as the clonedProjectId as the paremeter.

```
export const redeploy = (projectIdToClone) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(cloneProjectRequest(projectIdToClone))
    const projectIdNew = getState().projectReducer.projects[0].Project_ID
    dispatch(cloneParticipantRequest(projectIdToClone, projectIdNew))
}

const cloneProjectRequest = (projectIdToClone) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const result = await cloneProject(projectIdToClone)
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_LIST_ADD, payload: result })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error })
    }
}

const cloneParticipantRequest = (projectIdToClone, projectIdNew) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const result = await cloneParticipantsByProjectID(projectIdToClone, projectIdNew)
        result.foreach((participant) => {
            dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD, payload: participant })
        })
    } catch (e) {
        dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ERROR, payload: e.message })
    }
}
```

However, I cannot get the new created projectId after I dispatch the cloneProject function. **Is there a way I can get the updated project somehow?**

I was trying to dispatch cloneProjectRequest and cloneParticipantRequest seperate in handleRedeploy as well, but still cannot get the updated project list.

It is only working if I combine two actions together, but I will use a nested try catch, which I feel maybe wrong.

```
export const cloneProjectAndParticipant = (projectIdToClone) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const resultNewProject = await cloneProject(projectIdToClone)
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_LIST_ADD, payload: resultNewProject })
        try {
            const resultParticipants = await cloneParticipantsByProjectID(projectIdToClone, resultNewProject.id)
            resultParticipants.foreach((participant) => {
                dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ADD, payload: participant })
            })
        } catch (e) {
            dispatch({ type: PARTICIPANT_ERROR, payload: e.message })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: PROJECT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error })
    }
}
```

Can someone has idea how to fix this? Either I can get the lasted value of a reducer or I can get rid of nested try catch if I combine two actions together.

Comment: `await dispatch(cloneProjectRequest(projectIdToClone))`

Comment: Yes, it's working with await dispatch, I can get the latest value in this way, but is it a correct way?

Comment: Dispatch will return [the action](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) I can't find the documentation what it's supposed to return when middleware does not return `next(action)` but instead returns something else but I use it to chain thunk actions.

Comment: In your case you could also do `await cloneProjectRequest(projectIdToClone)(dispatch)`

Comment: Why dispatch is at the end of the statement? I've tried await dispatch(cloneProjectRequest(projectIdToClone)) and it's working? Any difference between putting dispatch to the end and my one?

Comment: Because cloneProjectRequest is a [curried function](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors#curry) you can either dispatch the function it returns or call it with dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

On the document, https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#connect

I think you need to add the following to the component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

/* component
   ...onClick={() => {
      this.props.handleRedeploy(Project_ID)
   }...
*/

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    handleRedeploy : (Project_ID) => redeploy(Project_ID)(dispatch)
  }
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(component);
```

Comment: No, I have use the dispatch hook to create the dispatch, const dispatch = useDispatch(), so the dispatch in my code has already applied what mapDispatchToProps does.

Comment: Oh, I haven't used like that, but try "await cloneProjectRequest(projectIdToClone)(dispatch)"

Comment: and however, I think dispatch function call to Reducers. So arguments for dispatch function should be like {type: PROJECT_LIST_FAIL, ..}, not void. And make sure dispatch parameter on redeploy function is correct.

Comment: No, dispatch with one function is dispatch a thunk action, your one with type is not the thunk action.